# how to get access token from created session using robot testing framework

Tags: python-2.7

Hi here is my script file.I would like to get access token from created session.I tried this way but I am getting access token as none.Can any help me.

```
    Create Session  httpbin     ${server_URL}       verify=${True}
&{dict}    Create Dictionary        username=${username}    password=${password}   email=${email}       role=${role}    
${header}  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json    charset=UTF-8     
${resp}     Post Request    httpbin     /api/Owners          data=${dict}    headers=${header}
${accessToken}=    evaluate    $resp.json().get("access_token")
Log to Console        ${accessToken}
log Many        ${resp.text}
${id}   Evaluate     $resp.json().get("id")
Log     ${id}
log to console      ${resp.status_code}
${resp}  Get Request     httpbin        uri=/api/Owners?access_token=${accessToken}
${resp}     Get Substring   ${resp.text}    1   -1
Log      ${resp}
${json_str}    Convert JSON To String    ${resp}
Should Contain      ${json_str}         ${id}
```

Answer (score 0):

using requests i will try to login and create an Token

```
import requests

login = {
      "user" : "username",
      "pass" : "passwrod",
}
```

here Write your own Token
that is only an Example

```
accesToken = {

"Accept" : "application/json",

}

request = requests.post('http://www.web.com/user', data=login, headers=accesToken')
```

Comment: Hi I have tried import requests but I am getting error saying that No keyword with name 'f' found.

Comment: did you tryed to install requests using pip install requests?

Comment: @PothuriSravanasandhya I Think it is An Error On your Machine Because Normaly It Will Import The Module And Send the Request without Error, and did you Definied the Accestoken?

Comment: @PothuriSravanasandhya Sorry I did A Mistake As I See On My Script I Will try to Edit it